# How to run graylog code base

Tags: maven-3, graylog2, graylog

I want to download and run graylog code base and make some changes in it

As of now i have fallowed below steps

Step 1 : 
Download graylog-project binay from this link https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog-project-cli/releases

Step2: Make `.linux` file  executable using below steps

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/bin
$ cp graylog-project.linux $HOME/bin/graylog-project
$ chmod +x $HOME/bin/graylog-project
```

Step3:
Execute this line :  `graylog-project bootstrap https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog-project.git`
this will clone all repositories via HTTPS

Step4: `mvn compile` fails to build with below error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project graylog2-server: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.graylog2:graylog2-server:jar:2.3.0-alpha.4-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:jar:2.25.1 -> org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.4.1.Final: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.4.1.Final: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-bom:pom:2.2.0 from/to sonatype-nexus-releases(https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:
```

i'm not able to figure out whats wrong any help will be greatly apreciated